# Vue.js-Electron application with an Apollo client does not receive cookies from a remote API server

Tags: nginx, vuejs3, apollo, nginx-reverse-proxy, electron-vue

I try to build an application with a [GraphQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphQL) backend (based on [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and graphql-yoga). The server is hosted on a Linux machine with [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) as a reverse proxy. The proxy configuration is listed below.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name url.example.com;

    charset utf-8;

    # Always serve index.html for any request
    location / {
        root /srv/app/public;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /graphql {
        allow all;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000$request_uri;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

   }

    location /playground {
        # Additional configuration
    }


    location /subscriptions {
        # Additional configuration
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/vue-app-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-access.log;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name url.example.com;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

To avoid [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problems, I had to add the following entry in my servers configuration and it works.

```
const options = {
  [
    ...
  ]
  /**
   * Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)
   */
  cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:8080', 'https://url.example.com'], // frontend url
  },
};
```

The authentication is based on [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) tokens packed into [http-only cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Http-only_cookie) for access and refresh tokens. This is working as expected when I access my server with a browser and the cookies are shown in the developer tools. Within the AuthData, I additionally provide the username and a JWT token as a return value.

```
{
    "data":{
        "login":{
            "user":"admin",
            "name":" Admin",
            "token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJhZG1pbiIsIm5hbWUiOiIgQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvciIsImVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW5AZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODM2MDcsImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ4NzIwN30.Dol41LStkscXrlGn3GJotf83k_d2EImyvDU68Dg8Bvw"
        }
    },
    "loading":false,
    "networkStatus":7
}
```

Now I wanted to play around with [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)), because some use cases of the application would be much easier. The stack is [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js) and Electron with [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/) and the Apollo client (I use the Apollo UploadClient here) as listed below.

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  DefaultOptions,
  InMemoryCache,
} from '@apollo/client/core';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';

const backendServer = 'https://url.example.com/graphql';

const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: backendServer,
  credentials: 'include',
});

// Cache implementation
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  addTypename: false,
}); //

const defaultOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
  mutate: {
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
} as DefaultOptions;

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => ({
  headers: {
    ...headers,
    /**
       * use a custom header tag to classify the application
       * for authentication handling in the backend
       */
    'app-type': 'web',
  },
}));

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([authLink, httpLink]),
  cache,
  defaultOptions,
  resolvers: {},
});

export default apolloClient;
```

This client is bound to my Vue.js instance via @vue/apollo-composable. So I think it is only available in the renderer process. React examples I found on the Internet were built the same way.

Now the problem: When I run server and client (Electron) application on my development machine, everything works as expected, and I can see the cookies in the application tab in the developer tools. I also can access the API without issues.

When I now bind my ApolloClient to the remote API server I do not receive any cookies. From the logs I can see that I receive the AuthData like above from the server, but not the cookies. So any further request results in a custom error message "unauthenticated access" provided by my API server.

```
{
    "loading":false,
    "networkStatus":8,
    "error":{
        "graphQLErrors":[
            {
                "message":"user is not authenticated...redirect to the login page",
                "locations":[
                    {"line":2,"column":3}
                ],
                "path":[
                    "users"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "clientErrors":[],
        "networkError":null,
        "message":"user is not authenticated...redirect to the login page"
    },"errors":[
        {
            "message":"user is not authenticated...redirect to the login page",
            "locations":[
                {"line":2,"column":3}
            ],
            "path":[
                "users"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong, or what else could I test?

**Additional tested direct access**

I additionally tested direct accessing the gql API from the electron client without the nginx proxy but still no success. I get the login correctly but I'm not able to see the cookies provided by the server.

any suggestions?

Comment: Same issue, please let me know if you've found the solution. Much appreciate it, and i'll return here if I find the solution.